# How to appendChild a generated div under a manually created div?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have a div element that is generated by a javascript library. Let's assume the ID for it is `auto`

And I manually created a HTML div element with an ID of `manual`.

How do I move the generated `div#auto` into `div#manual`?

The div elements that are generated are not part of the document tree.
So I can't just `appendChild` to put `auto` under `manual`

Any idea?

```js
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = 'generated';

var el = document.getElementById('element');
console.log(el)
```

```html
<div id="manual">Place #generated as child of me</div>
```

As you can see, I can't target the generated div element #generated because it is not in the document tree. If I can't select it, I can't place it under #manual.

Comment: PLease show some code.

Comment: The library should not return an ID, which is a poor man's way to reference DOM elements, and cannot be used to find them unless they are already in the tree. Instead, it should return the DOM element itself, which you could then just insert under `manual`.

Comment: In this [bin](http://jsbin.com/midaya/edit?html,css,js,output) I'm doing exactly this. Isn't?

Comment: Given the number of JS libraries out there, "generated by" could mean quite a lot of different things. Some code would be very helpful - especially to understand what you mean by "not part of the document tree." If it's on the page, its definitely in the DOM.

Comment: Sorry for being vague but I am not sure what is the best way to articulate this. I have created a codepen to demonstrate my problem. http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/rLMmXa When I meant generated, I mean the div element is created with pure JS. It isn't a div element in HTML.

Comment: @Vennsoh: Rather than off-site resources, put the [mcve] **in** the question as a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the tip! Added it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = 'generated';

var el = document.getElementById('element');
console.log(el)
```

`element` is **already** a reference to the element. There's no reason to try to look it up again via `getElementById`; just use the reference you have. `getElementById` won't find it, because it's not in the DOM yet.

So just use `element`:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = 'generated';

document.querySelector("#manual").appendChild(element);
// -------------------------------------------^
```

At *that* point, it's in the DOM and `getElementById` would find it (though, again, you don't need to; you already have a reference to it in `element`).

Live Example: *(I've added borders and given the generated div some content to make it clear what the result is)*

```js
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = 'generated';
element.innerHTML = "generated";

document.querySelector("#manual").appendChild(element);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="manual">Place #generated as child of me</div>
```

Note that there's no need for the `id` on the generated div for you to do this. If you have a *different* reason for it having an `id`, that's fine, but you don't need it for this:

```js
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = "generated";

document.querySelector("#manual").appendChild(element);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="manual">Place generated div as child of me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! And that's the problem. If you inspect the source, #generated doesn't get placed as a child under #manual. Because #generated isn't in the document yet. How do I insert the generated div element into the document tree? Divs that are written in HTML (in document tree). Divs that are coded with JS (not in document tree).

Comment: @Vennsoh: *"If you inspect the source, #generated doesn't get placed as a child under #manual."* "View Source" doesn't show you the current state of the DOM, it shows you the HTML delivered from the server. To see the current state of the DOM, on modern browsers you can right-click the element and choose "Inspect" or "Inspect Element".

Comment: @Vennsoh: *"How do I insert the generated div element into the document tree?"* That's what `appendChild` does (along with its cousins `insertBefore`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder To further demonstrate my question of div elements created in JS won't be in the document tree. I have edited the snippet. If you try to getDocumentByID() of the generated div, it will return "null" because it is not in the tree.

Comment: @Vennsoh: Correct. When you create an element, it isn't in the tree yet; the only way to reference the element is with the reference returned by `createElement`. But once you put it in a parent, as my code above does with `appendChild`, it's in the tree.